# How to add multiple "date" columns to Editable Grid and still have it work properly?

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I'm using Editable Gridhttp://www.editablegrid.net/en/faq to make my database editable.I downloaded everything and set it up and it works perfectly only that when i added multiple "date" Columns the format of the date comes back as 000-00-00 which is the standard mysql format instead as the original  day/month(in letters)/year format that the demo column displays to the user. i am a total noob to the max in PHP and jQuery. Any advice or insight to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.I added a not at the end of the script from the line I suspect is the problem.

```
/**
 * This script loads data from the database and returns it to the js
 *
 */

require_once('config.php');      
require_once('EditableGrid.php');            

/**
 * fetch_pairs is a simple method that transforms a mysqli_result object in an array.
 * It will be used to generate possible values for some columns.
*/
function fetch_pairs($mysqli,$query){
    if (!($res = $mysqli->query($query)))return FALSE;
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $first = true;
        $key = $value = null;
        foreach ($row as $val) {
            if ($first) { $key = $val; $first = false; }
            else { $value = $val; break; } 
        }
        $rows[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $rows;
}


// Database connection
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$mysqli->real_connect($config['db_host'],$config['db_user'],$config['db_password'],$config['db_name']); 

// create a new EditableGrid object
$grid = new EditableGrid();

/* 
*  Add columns. The first argument of addColumn is the name of the field in the databse. 
*  The second argument is the label that will be displayed in the header
*/
$grid->addColumn('id', 'ID', 'integer', NULL, false);
$grid->addColumn('freelance', 'Complete', 'boolean');  
 $grid->addColumn('name', 'Name', 'string');
 $grid->addColumn('id_continent', 'Assigned To', 'string' , fetch_pairs($mysqli,'SELECT id, name FROM continent'),true);  
$grid->addColumn('lastvisit', 'Assigned Date', 'date');  
$grid->addColumn('cdate', 'CheckDate', 'date');  
$grid->addColumn('ddate', 'DueDate', 'date');  

  /* The column id_country and id_continent will show a list of all available countries and continents. So, we select all rows from the tables */
  //Ramon note that "NULL,false" here means that it cannot be edited so ponte trucha, cabron!!!!
$grid->addColumn('email', 'Email', 'html',NULL,false);                                               
               //I suspect it has to do with this line.Question poster comment.                                                        
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT *, date_format(lastvisit, "%d/%m/%Y") as lastvisit FROM demo LIMIT 100');

$mysqli->close();

// send data to the browser
$grid->renderXML($result);
```

Comment: please anyone with comments?

Comment: Please understand that we can not provide support for third-party scripts here. Please contact the vendor of the software you use here for your support options. Or boil down the issue you have to a concrete programming question and ask about it instead.

Comment: You might like this: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php - let me know if it was helpful for you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT *, date_format(lastvisit, "%d/%m/%Y") as lastvisit, date_format(anotherdate, "%d/%m/%Y") as anotherdate FROM demo LIMIT 100');
```

use `date_format(fieldname, formatstring) as name_as_you_want_it_returned`for every date

Comment: Hahahahahaha. Dude this is the so simple yet ,dude, it worked!!!! I really need to bone up on my PHP!!! I love PHP btw! Your rock tho! Thanks ,homie. I got your back michi. Also Thank you stackoverflow! i love this community of programming gurus and geeks. All you vatos are all right! thanks a bunch.Just makes me want to take in more and everything about php and all other server side languages. Yea!!

Comment: Could you please explain it?